# Stop content jumping due to ad load

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, adsense

When we load google ads, it usually fills the empty ad block slot after page load.

I have noticed one thing where in Chrome browser, initially ads slot divs are loading with auto height or a minimum height so that even after ad content load, page content is not jumping.

But for Firefox, initially all ad slots are collapsed with zero height and when it loads ad content, whole page content jump a bit which is really annoying.

Is there any way to fix the issue?

I am using responsive ads which loads different size ads based on device.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming your not using responsive ads so why not just set the parent div to the size of the ad so its there just waiting to be filled and positioning the content below it below by the amount the ad will be?

Comment: I am using responsive ads which loads different size ads based on device.

Answer (score 0):

If the ad slot to be responsive. then you might need to look at [data-ad-format](https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-adsense-responsive-design/25252/)

otherwise you can use min-height css property and set it ad element. see here [min-height](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

Comment: actually this is a responsive ad unit and even it I set a minimum height, it might look fine in desktop but for mobile, it will take extra height as mobile ads are usually smaller.